# Freemarker global variable value getting appended twice

Tags: java, freemarker

I am assigning global variable a value but when i am using it i am getting it twice#

```
<#global "base"="abc/xyz"></global>
```

When i am using ${base} i am getting abc/xyz/abc/xyz.

Comment: _"When i am using ${base}"_ -- SHOW US where you use `${base}`

Comment: it holds the root context of application and i am appending uri to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you check the [global docs](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_global.html) your syntax is wrong, the options are:

> <#global name=value> or
>
> <#global name1=value1 name2=value2 ...
> nameN=valueN> or
>
> <#global name>    capture this < /#global>

The easiest option is

```
<#global base="abc/xyz">
```

Also to make sure you are using the **global** variable:

```
${.globals.abc}
```

> For example, with <#global x = 1> you create a variable that is
> visible as x in all namespaces, unless another variable called x hides
> it (for example a variable what you have created as <#assign x = 2>).
> In this case, you can use special variable globals, like ${.globals.x}

Comment: Actually, it's allowed to quote the target variable, though it's needless if it's called `base`.

Comment: Using `.globals.base` instead of `base` is only needed if there's a non-global `base` that hides it.

Comment: yes, but also OP syntax uses `</global>` which is not in docs syntax

Comment: Ah... haven't noticed the `</global>` tag, that's indeed wrong. As it's not even `</#global>` (note the `#`), it will silently print `</global>`.